# Probability of drawing a spade on the first draw, a heart on the second draw, and an ace on the third draw

Tags: probability

My answer is

$(\frac{1}{52})(\frac{1}{51})(\frac{2}{50})$ + $2(\frac{1}{52})(\frac{12}{51})(\frac{3}{50})$ + $(\frac{12}{52})(\frac{12}{51})(\frac{4}{50})$

= $\frac{1}{204}$

But the answer in the textbook is

$(\frac{13}{52})(\frac{13}{51})(\frac{2}{50})$ + $2(\frac{13}{52})(\frac{13}{51})(\frac{3}{50})$ + $(\frac{13}{52})(\frac{13}{51})(\frac{4}{50})$

= $\frac{13}{850}$

Which answer is correct?

Comment: The book is, of course.

Comment: Books aren't always correct.

Comment: @zwim And when they aren't, they can lead to m.se questions!

Comment: @zwim You are right! The order of spades, hearts and aces isn't relevant. These are exchangeable events. For instance the probability that card 1 is an ace, card 2 a heart and card 3 a spade is the same as the probability requested here.

Comment: Add to @LordSharktheUnknown's reply, the order has the effect on $n(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(A) = \frac{n(A)}{n(\Omega)}$$
Here, $$n(A) = n(\text{ace of spade}) \times n(\text{ace of heart}) \times n(\text{other aces}) + \\ n(\text{spade other than ace}) \times n(\text{ace of heart}) \times n(\text{other aces}) + \\ n(\text{ace of spade}) \times n(\text{ heart other than ace}) \times n(\text{other aces}) + \\ n(\text{spade other than ace}) \times n(\text{ heart other than ace}) \times n(\text{aces})$$
$$=1 \times 1 \times 2+ 2 \times 12 \times 1 \times 3 + 12 \times 12 \times 4$$
$$ = 2+72+576=650$$

$$n(\Omega)= 52 \times 51 \times 50 $$
So, $P(A) =1/204$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of drawing a spade followed by a heart followed by the ace of spades or hearts is
$$\frac{12\times13}{51\times 50}\times\frac2{52}.$$
The probability of drawing a spade followed by a heart followed by the ace of diamonds or clubs is is
$$\frac{13^2}{51\times 50}\times\frac2{52}.$$
These add to
$$\frac{13\times25}{51\times50}\times\frac2{52}=\frac1{204}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the probability tree diagram:

[image]